# How to extract Certain nth character from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field that returns the value as xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xx-x. How do i extract the 10th character from that code.

Comment: What do you class as the 10th character in your example? The 1st `x` in the 4th group, or the 2nd `x` in the 3rd group?

Answer (score 28):

```
select substring('xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xx-x', 10, 1)
```

The documentation for the function on MSDN is <kbd>[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)</kbd>.

The SQL Fiddle demo is <kbd>[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/36424)</kbd> (with different letters so you can clearly see which letter is extracted).

Answer (score 6):

Use `substring` function

select substring('xxx-xxx-xax-xxxxx-xx-x', 10, 1)

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), in your case use...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, 10, 1)
```

**field** being the one that returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x varchar(20) = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xx-x'

select SUBSTRING(@x,10,CHARINDEX('-',@x)-4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code will return the nth substring after delimiting, either from left or from right; in the particular example the  delimiter is comma, and it is looking for the 2nd segment, counting from right

```
declare

@str_orig VARCHAR(256)='123,345,8,6,7',
@delimit varchar(50) =',',
@loc int =2,
@from_left bit =0



SELECT value, row_number()  over( order by( select 1)) as row_num
into #split
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str_orig, @delimit)

declare @result varchar(256)
if @from_left=1
 begin
 set @result = ( select top 1  value  from  #split  where row_num=@loc)
 end
else
 begin

 set @result = ( select top 1  value  from  #split
 where row_num= (SELECT MAX(ROw_num) -(@loc-1) FROM  #split)
 )
 
 end


select @result
```